# CodeIgniter - Checking to see if a slug already exists in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have made a function `add_items`. and I Want if the slug already exists in the `database` then the `form_validation` runs and shows the `error message`. and that's work fine if the `slug exists`. But the main `problem` is that if I want to `insert` the `new Data` in the `database` which obviously has a different `slug` then the `data` is not inserted.

```
public function add_items()
    {
       if($this->input->post()){
           if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
               $title = $this->input->post('title');
               $url_title = url_title($title);
                $this->form_validation->set_rules($url_title,'callback_slug_exists');
                    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                    {
                      echo "FAIL::Slug Already Exist::error";
                      return;
                    }
                    $item_price = $this->input->post('item_price');
                    $item_description = $this->input->post('item_description');
                    $insertData = array('item_title' =>$title,'item_url'=>$url_title,'item_price' =>$item_price,'item_description'=>$item_description,
                       'big_pic' =>$image_path."/".$image);
                    $result = $this->common_model->insert_record('store_items',$insertData);
                       if($result){
                         echo "OK::Record Inserted Successfully::success";
                         return;
                       }
                       else {
                         echo "FAIL::Record Insertion Failled::success";
                         return;
                       }

                   }
               }

            $this->show('admin/add_items.php');
}
```

Here are The `function slug_exists()`

```
 function slug_exists($slug)
       {
           $this->common_model->slug_exists($slug);
       }
```

This is in Model

```
 function slug_exists($slug)
 {
     $this->db->where('item_url',$slug);
     $query = $this->db->get('store_items');
     if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
         return true;
     }
     else{
         return false;
     }
 }
```

This is the `insert_record()`

```
  function insert_record($tbl, $data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($tbl, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

And this is DB Structure

[image]

Comment: actually slug is the thing which we generate, its nothing to do with end user who use the system. You must have a mechanism that if slug is already exists, then generate a unique one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:you can post data direct in an array. no need define it.

```
$insertArray=array(
item_title' =>$this->input->post('title'),
'item_url'=>$this->input->post('url_title'),
'item_price' =>$this->input->post('item_price'),
'item_description'=>$this->input->post('item_description'),
'big_pic' =>$image_path."/".$image);
$this->db->insert('store_items', $insertArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function slug_exists($slug)
{
   $this->db->where('item_url',$slug);
   $query = $this->db->get('store_items');
   if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
       return false;
   }
   else{
       return true;
   }
}
```

If slug already exists then you need to fail the validation to get the error so return `false` on existing

Also, return the answer/result to a callback function

```
function slug_exists($slug)
{
   return $this->common_model->slug_exists($slug);
}
```

**Update**

**Controller**

```
 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
echo "FAIL::Slug Already Exist::error";
return;
 }else{

$item_price = $this->input->post('item_price');
$item_description = $this->input->post('item_description');
$insertData = array('item_title' =>$title,'item_url'=>$url_title,'item_price' =>$item_price,'item_description'=>$item_description,
    'big_pic' =>$image_path."/".$image);
$result = $this->common_model->insert_record('store_items',$insertData);
if($result){
    echo "OK::Record Inserted Successfully::success";
    return;
}
else {
    echo "FAIL::Record Insertion Failled::success";
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: yes if the slug exists I get the error message. but if not exists then new data is not inserted.

Comment: add `insert_record()` function and DB structure in question

Comment: Ok I will do it now

Comment: Please check the question I have updated the question.

Comment: @JohnDoe the image of DB is not related to structure. Click on the structure button and then take the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190739/discussion-between-john-doe-and-danish-ali).